# AWS ssh access 'Permission denied (publickey)' issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

How to connect to a AWS instance through ssh?

I have:

1. Signed up at AWS;
2. Created a public key and a certificate at AWS website and saved them to disk;
3. Went to my console and created environment variables:

   ```
   $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/
   $ export EC2_CERT=/home/default/aws/cert-EBAINCRNWHDSCWWIHSOKON2YWGJZ5LSQ.pem
   $ export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/home/default/aws/pk-EBAINCRNWHDSCWWIHSOKON2YWGJZ5LSQ.pem
   ```
4. Told AWS API to use this keypair and saved the keypair to file:

   ```
   $ ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair > ec2-keypair.pem
   ```
5. Started an AWS Ubuntu 9 instance using this keypair:

   ```
   $ ec2-run-instances ami-ed46a784 -k ec2-keypair
   ```
6. Attempted to establish a ssh connection to the instance:

   ```
   $ ssh -v -i ec2-keypair.pem ubuntu@ec2-174-129-185-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com
   OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: Applying options for *
   debug1: Connecting to ec2-174-129-185-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com [174.129.185.190] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file ec2-keypair.pem type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug1: Host 'ec2-174-129-185-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /home/default/.ssh/known_hosts:11
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Trying private key: ec2-keypair.pem
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
   Permission denied (publickey).
   ```

   What could be the problem and how to make it work?

Comment: Ironic is that I use "root" as user name but "ubuntu" (what you mentioned) is the right name for my AMI, and thank you for your post!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied (publickey) when SSH Access to Amazon EC2 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551556/permission-denied-publickey-when-ssh-access-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

Comment: bruh this was asked 4 years earlier @CtheGood

Answer (score 557, accepted):

For Ubuntu instances:

```
chmod 600 ec2-keypair.pem
ssh -v -i ec2-keypair.pem ubuntu@ec2-174-129-185-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

For other instances, you might have to use `ec2-user` instead of `ubuntu`.

Most EC2 Linux images I've used only have the root user created by default.

See also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBro0TEAd7g

Comment: You can also use ssh-add ec2-keypair.pem so you can drop the -i option

Comment: We're having the same problem - when we use root, it tells us to log back in as ubuntu... but as ubuntu it just fails as the above example.

Comment: if you try root and you get "Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.'" use **ec2-user** in place of root.

Comment: Cheesy is right, however at least the -v option helped figuring this out. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: And some Ubuntu images seem to have the "ubuntu" user only.  (Which can sudo to root.)

Comment: @AdamK "You can also use ssh-add ec2-keypair.pem so you can drop the -i option",  so can i login through putty in windows also ???

Comment: @AshokKS To log in with Putty you should download PuttyGen and convert your .pem file to a .ppk (putty format). Then use the .ppk via Pagent or in the 'Auth' portion of Putty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It blows my mind that Amazon still hasn't updated their documentations to make this little known fact more known :) They don't actually mention the need to have a user@... Maybe assuming people would remember.

Comment: for Amazon Linux AMI, you will need to use ec2-user@<instancePublicDNS> like ssh -v -i ec2-keypair.pem ec2-user@ec2-174-129-185-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: ubuntu@<instancePublicDNS> worked for me. ec2-user did not.

Comment: On file mode 600, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21625290/843660

Comment: Currently for security reasons it should be:  chmod 400 ec2-keypair.pem

Comment: LOLing at the fact that this went back to 2009. I just had the same issue, i usually go with Amazon Linux but went with Ubuntu this time around cause i wanted to use `authbind` (not available on Yum). Why can't they have one username set for all environments?

Answer (score 94):

Now it's:

```
ssh -v -i ec2-keypair.pem ec2-user@[yourdnsaddress]
```

Comment: Thanks. It took me ages to find this out - it's not mentioned in the connect info from the console! It does tell you when you try to use root, but I thought ec2-user was a reference to my username. Doh!

Answer (score 48):

Canonical's releases use the user 'ubuntu' by default for anyone landing here with a ubuntu image that is coming up with the same problem.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using a Bitnami image, log in as 'bitnami'.

Seems obvious, but something I overlooked.

Comment: Did you mean? `Seems <sarcasm>obvious</sarcasm>`

Comment: [Bitnami instructions](https://bitnami.com/aws-credentials), including how to find the database passwords.

Comment: This made my day.

Answer (score 9):

For my ubuntu images, it is actually ubuntu user and NOT the ec2-user ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 10.04 with openSSH

this is the exact usage:

```
ssh -v -i [yourkeypairfile] ec2-user@[yourdnsaddress]
```

for example:

```
ssh -v -i GSG_Keypair.pem ec2-user@ec2-184-72-204-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

above example was taken directly from the AWS tutorial for connecting to a Linux/UNIX machine at:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

Comment: With ssh -i switch we can use .pem file only.

Answer (score 5):

It will also complain if the pem file permissions are too open. chmod the file to 600 to fix that.

Comment: For novices.. the command to do this would be:
`chmod 600 your_file.pem`

Answer (score 5):

I was also running into this - turns out I was using a community-created AMI - and the default username was niehter root, nor was it ect-user or ubuntu. In fact, I had no idea what it was - till I tried '**root**' and the server kindly asked me to login as **xxx** where **xxx** is whatever it tells you.

-cheers!

Answer (score 5):

If you are running AWS image from Bitnami. The username would be bitnami. Cheers!

see my debug and look at the last one:

*

```
ssh -v -i awsliferaysrta.pem.txt root@54.254.250.***
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.254.250.*** [54.254.250.***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file awsliferaysrta.pem.txt type -1
debug1: identity file awsliferaysrta.pem.txt-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 05:5c:78:45:c9:39:3a:84:fe:f8:19:5d:31:48:aa:5f
debug1: Host '54.254.250.***' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: awsliferaysrta.pem.txt
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 54.254.250.*** ([54.254.250.***]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Please login as the user "bitnami" rather than the user "root".
```

*

Answer (score 5):

You need have your private key in your local machine

You need to know the IP address or DNS name of your remote machine or server, you can get this from AWS console

If you are a linux user

- Make sure the permissions on the private key are 600
  (`chmod 600 <path to private key file>`)
- Connect to your machine using **ssh**
  (`ssh -i <path to private key file> <user>@<IP address or DNS name of remote server>`)

If you are a windows user

- Use PuTTy to create the ssh session (http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty-0.66-installer.exe)
- If your private key file is in .pem format convert it into .ppk using **puttygen**
- Launch PuTTy, set you ppk file, IP address or DNS name of the remote server and start the ssh session

Comment: Change the permission of the file using chmod 400 <pem key>

Answer (score 4):

use...

```
# chmod 400 ec2-keypair.pem
```

don't use the 600 permission otherwise you might overwrite your key accidently.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian EC2 instances, the user is `admin`.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 steps to be connected:

Chmod 400 on your private key, like this the others cannot access to your key:

```
chmod 400 toto.pem
```

To connect to your instance in SSH, you need to know the public IP address of your instance :

```
ssh -i toto.pem ec2-user@XX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
ssh-keygen -R <server_IP>
```

to delete the old keys stored on the workstation
also works with  instead of

then doing the same ssh again it worked:

```
ssh -v -i <your_pem_file> ubuntu@<server_IP>
```

on ubuntu instances the username is: ubuntu
on Amazon Linux AMI the username is: ec2-user

I didn't have to re-create the instance from an image.

Answer (score 2):

Permission for `ec2-keypair.pem` should be `400`

`chmod 400 ec2-keypair.pem`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EBS, you can also try to mount the EBS Volume on a running instance. Then mount it on that running instance and see what's going on in /home. You can see things like is the user ubuntu or ec2-user ? or does it have the right public keys under ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Mac OS X), the problem was the file's break type. Try this:

1.- Open the .pem file with TextWrangler

2.- At Bottom of app, verify if the Break Type is "Windows(CRLF)".

Answer (score 1):

Its ec2-user for Amazon Linux AMI's and ubuntu for Ubuntu images. 
Also, RHEL 6.4 and later    ec2-user
RHEL 6.3 and earlier    root
Fedora  ec2-user
Centos  root

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to this list.  I was having trouble this morning with a new user just added to an AWS EC2 instance.  To cut to the chase, the problem was **selinux** (which was in **enforcing** mode), together with the fact that my user home dir was on a new EBS attached volume.  Somehow I guess selinux doesn't like that other volume.  Took me a while to figure out, as I looked through all the other usual ssh issues (/etc/ssh/sshd_config was fine, of course no password allowed, permissions were right, etc.)

The fix?

For now (until I understand how to allow a user to ssh to a different volume, or somehow make that volume a bona fide home dir point):

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's/^SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config
sudo setenforce 0
```

That's it. Now my new user can log in, using his own id_rsa key.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Permission denied (publickey) when trying to login in with 'ec2-user' or with 'root'.

Googled the AMI number of the machine image and it had the SSH login information right their on the Debian wiki page.

Hope this helps.