# Trying to get data off of my Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get data off my EC2 instance using Filezilla and I'm trying to connect to the instance using the credentials I've used in the past, but I am now getting an error.

- The instance is located at the IP: 23.23.152.36
- I am connecting via port 22
- I have tried via the user-name ec2-user and the user-name root
- I created a new private key, downloaded .pem file, and then add that private key in Filezilla preferences.

When I add the .pem file, it converts it to a .ppk and I save it as the same name.ppk

However, I'm getting this error is Filezilla:

Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't download a new key. The instance will keep the old key.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a new private key, downloaded .pem file,

This step is unnecessary. You need the original key with which the instance was launched.

If in case you lost that key then there is a hard way to login using a new key as mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269279/1251660