# How to grant another user for connecting an AMI on AWS to work on it without giving .pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp

I have launched a linux server on AWS, there is another developer and i want him to work on the server, but i don't want to give .pem file to him, what should i do?

he should be able to connect to server via a console and deploy files and configure on http server. when the jobs done i want to take his priviliges back.

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add his public ssh key to `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` and that's basically it.

He will be able to login via SSH using corresponding private key.

This have nothing to do with AMI though.

Comment: i am not good at ssh topics, please let me know i understood wright. You mean He should create his own ssh key on his local machine and give his public key to me to add on server. if it's so, is there any practical tool or other things to do that? or i should  find how to create ssh key document? thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend : https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20ssh%20key&safe=off

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution [here](http://utkarshsengar.com/2011/01/manage-multiple-accounts-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance/), new user and a new key/pair for that user can be created on server machine. new user can access to server with the new key.

Another anwers about same topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260739/add-keypair-to-existing-ec2-instance?lq=1)

Comment: you should not create the key on server. private key should be private and created by your employee (chances are he already has one).