# can't ssh in after cloning an EC2 instance on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a working m3.large instance on Amazon AWS that I'm able to login to using a username and a password via ssh.  I've cloned it by creating an AMI of it and then spinning up another m3.large instance based on that AMI, but I cannot ssh into it. In putty, after typing in my username, I get "Server refused our key"
followed by Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey).  Shouldn't the new cloned instance behave exactly like the one the AMI came from? Shouldn't the only difference be their IP addresses?

Comment: Take a look at these questions:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454629/aws-ssh-access-permission-denied-publickey-issue


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260739/add-keypair-to-existing-ec2-instance

Comment: Ok i figured out that the problem was in the original instance, the one I'd cloned.  In its /etc/ssh/sshd_config, i'd neglected to include the line 

PasswordAuthentication yes

For some reason even with it set to no I could login on the original instance, but not on the clone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured out that the problem was in the original instance, the one I'd cloned. In its /etc/ssh/sshd_config, i'd neglected to include the line PasswordAuthentication yes For some reason even with it set to no I could login on the original instance, but not on the clone.