# How to pull files from AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have created a instance through elastic beanstalk. I did't link any ssh key while creating. SO I cant connect with putty or with sfth. I can deploy data to the instance by this command -> eb deploy .

How can I fetch files from the instance. anyone know the solutions?

Comment: Please see the following question and see if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260739/add-keypair-to-existing-ec2-instance

Comment: @JordonPhillips Nope, But Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

-Login to Aws manage console.
-Select elastic beanstalk in services.
-Select your application.
-Download the version.

Comment: this will download the app version, not instance files as requested.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't connect any ssl key, you have no access to the web instance. the only way in is via port 80 (your app). Therefore, you can't pull any files. You'll have to recreate the elastic beanstalk environment and this time add a key.