# 'Can't connect to MySQL server' on AWS RDS direct access

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made ElasticBeansTalk App on AWS. I couldn't access rds via command console.

```
mysql -uusername -p -h vegeweldb.xxxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'vegeweldb.xxxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)
```

Also, can't access ec2 using ssh.

```
ssh -i some.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-164.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I made key pair on AWS. I can't figure out why. I'd appreciate if you give some advice.

BTW here's current configuration.
[image]

Comment: Is your RDS instance in a VPC?  Are you trying to access from an EC2 instance?  Have you opened the appropriate ports in the RDS db security group?

Comment: My RDS is in VPC. I'm now so sure about whether it's right or not. I put the screenshot on AWS. Could you examine it?

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa is your EC2 instance in a VPC ? If Yes, have you attached elastic IP or public IP to that EC2 instance? Also, the "some.pem" was the same key that was associated with the EC2 instance ? IF you are not able to SSH to EC2 instance itself, from where are you trying to connect to RDS instance (which is inside VPC)?

Comment: @Ashish-G Thanks for the comment. I cant either access rds or ec2.
 ssh -i some.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
Here's the result. If I accessed to ec2, I could reach out rds, maybe.

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa ok, you might want to recheck that the VPC setup is correct -- Is the internet gateway (IGW) configured? Is the route table setup from the EC2 subnet to IGW? Is the security group (SG) used by EC2 instance has SSH (tcp/22) open from source 0.0.0.0/0 (_or_ your custom specific source)?

Comment: @Ashish-G I already checked along with your advice. And I've noticed no keypair is attached to ec2 instance. But I can't figure out how to attach keypair with ec2. Do you know that?

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa...oh, thats bit tricky, pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260739/add-keypair-to-existing-ec2-instance ;  BTW, if its just a recent instance setup and/or not in production yet, it might be faster to spin up a new instance with key-pair associated & terminate current one.

Comment: @Ashish-G I didn't notice assigning key-pair on existing instance. I re-created my instance using beanstalk. Maybe it works. I'll let you know when it turns out. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @NoriakiTakamizawa So when you created the EC2 instance you cannot create it without attaching a key pair to it.