# permission denied (public key issue)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created an instance of amazon unix/linux on aws ec2, when i tried to access my instance from my ubuntu console I am getting an error "ssh -i mpigeon.pem ec2-50-17-134-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey)."

What is the issue how do I resolve it

Comment: You didn't get the chance to put in a username? If so what AMI are you using and which username?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS ssh access 'Permission denied (publickey)' issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454629/aws-ssh-access-permission-denied-publickey-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mention the user name while login into instance.

`ssh -i mpigeon.pem root@ec2-50-17-134-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

If you are using ubuntu instance, default user in ubuntu. Replace root user with ubuntu user else for centos and fedora, default user is root only.

Comment: I have switched to the ubuntu instance now, I am able to access the instance now I need to install apache tomcat and also java