# upload files to ec2 from local using scp

Tags: file-upload, amazon-ec2, web2py, scp

I am using scp to upload files from local to ec2, and I got the permission error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your ssh keys uploaded.

Here's a link to an article showing you how to set this up:

http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys

Also, see this:

[AWS ssh access 'Permission denied (publickey)' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454629/aws-ssh-access-permission-denied-publickey-issue)