# Unable to connect SSH key, Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to connect AWS and I am getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The only things I have are:

- User Name
- Host
- a 20 char Key

I am running the command `ssh -i <KEY> user@host`

Comment: Which image ? are you trying to connect with the pem file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS SSH connection error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392763/aws-ssh-connection-error-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 1):

Perform below steps,

```
 sudo chmod 400 <KEY-NAME>.pem
 sudo ssh -i "<KEY-NAME>.pem" <username>@<host>
```

Make sure username is right one as username can be root, ec2-user, ubuntu etc.

if it doesn't solve your issue then please share information with debugger by running ssh command with -vv.

```
 sudo ssh -i "<KEY-NAME>.pem" <username>@<host> -vv
```

Answer (score 0):

For me editing the ssh configuration file and changing `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes` worked. So just type:

`sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Edit the file and then restart ssh service:

`sudo service ssh restart`

Then you will able to login with any created user without using the pen certificate that is only intended to login as ubuntu user (i.e. similar to root).