# SSH permission denied (publickey) and unstable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

My server is down and I don't know why.
My server run with Nodejs, Dynamodb
SSH unstable
I got this error when try connect

> ssh -vvv -i "xxxx.pem" ubuntu@xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.                                                                                                                com

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Can you please clarify if the issue is your server is down as in shut down ? Or the issue is that you are unable to SSH ? Please elaborate and provide relevant error entries and ask specific questions for getting help.

Comment: try by providing proper permission to `pem` file.

chmod 400 {keyfile}.pem

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454629/aws-ssh-access-permission-denied-publickey-issue

Comment: What error message did you receive? Also, does it give the error immediately or does it take some time (eg 10 seconds) for the error to appear?